# Edit the source code of external libraries in PyCharm with remote interpreter

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pycharm, remote-debugging

I have a setup of PyCharm with docker-compose remote interpreter.
So... I want to be able to change the source code of some external packages.
I'm doing this within the remote interpreter... But the changes are not being reflected in the container.
How to make it work?

Comment: I am thinking about something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55784400/listen-to-changes-and-reload-container-on-code-change-docker-compose but for your environment.

Comment: What about using a tool in your image to watch for the files and restart when they do change?